# Calculate the distance between two points on a sphere (earth) going through the earth?

Tags: geometry, distance, spherical-geometry

I can see the formula and name of the term for the distance between any two points on a sphere when going *around* the surface of the sphere is the [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#:%7E:text=The%20great%2Dcircle%20distance%20or,line%20through%20the%20sphere%27s%20interior), or orthodromic distance.

What is the calculation for the distance between any two points on a sphere going directly ***through*** the sphere?

Comment: couldn't you solve that using simple 3D pythagoras?

Comment: @IanTurton maybe, I don't quite know what that is though! Is that an equation or some software?

Comment: d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy *dy + dz+dz) where dx = x2-x1 and dy and dz are similar

Comment: @IanTurton thanks very much. Just checking is  `dz+dz` meant to be `dz*dz`

Comment: The equation can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Tunnel_distance). It has to take angles into considerations

Comment: GIS generally operates on a sheroid, and doesn't generally bore through the Earth (and if it does, it *has* to use a spheroid), so this is more of a pure [math.se] question.

Comment: @Vince - *Any* GIS question requiring an equation good be dismissed as a pure math problem, but i don't think we do that (reject as theory) here. I prefer to accept as good faith any geographical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, calculate the great circle distance, **G**, using your GIS or spherical trigonometry (or look for various questions on this site).

Then calculate the angular distance, **α = G / R**. (R is globe radius.)

Finally, use those to calculate chord length, **L = 2 R sin (α / 2)**.

One source: [mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html).

Or, use the [Tunnel_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Tunnel_distance) equation, as suggested by JGH.

Comment: Hi @Martin F thanks very much! I tried it, and the answer I get is identical to the starting value for G ?

Comment: here's my R code `G = 5.25; R = 6371; α = G / R; 2 * R * (sin(α / 2))`

Comment: Your G is small to have any meaningful difference. If G smaller than 11km then it can be assumed to be flat.